# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() , cpanel fix

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

my website recently crashed and is no longer available. I browsed through my Cpanel dashboard and I found error logs file in which I noticed my website is crashing due to call to undefined function mysqli_connect. Website is using PHP version 7.4. I tried downgrading PHP version myself but it didn't help. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this using c panel.

Comment: PHP has extensions to extend his functions. One of them is the mysqli extension. it seems like the appropriate mysqli extension is no longer installed or active.

Comment: When i go to php selector i see mysqli extension as enabled, do you have any other suggestion on how i can check if extension is really active and installed.

Comment: Sorry, i never worked with Cpanel. If you have multiple php-versions, be sure mysqli is enabled for every version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in any test php file
`echo phpinfo();`
and look for mysqli extension if its disabled.

This fatal error comes when mysqli extension is disabled.

you can set it explicitly from php.ini for version you selected from cpanel.

for more information look here https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-enable-mysqli.142737/

Answer (score 0):

this problem has nothing to do with the cpanel

The problem is with the server PHP settings

You can rewrite the connection section with PDO

read more :

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp